# Can we use aync await instead of promise?

Tags: redux, async-await

```
getTasksOfUser:  (userId, filterParams) => {
            return  dispatch(getMyTasksOfUserInActionStation(userId, filterParams)).then((res) => {
                return Promise.resolve(res);
            }, (error) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
        },
```

Comment: Fundamentally, adding `.then((res) => {return Promise.resolve(res);}, (error) => {return Promise.reject(error);}` to an existing promise is (effectively) an no-op.

Comment: We can, but there is nothing in your code snippet that we need to `await`. Only one `dispatch()` call. What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.